# Getting my PHP Slime Framework Application to run in a Hosted Environment?

Tags: php, apache, hosting, web-hosting, slim

**Introduction**

Hi all. I've currently completed the development for my first PHP web application - a very simple one built using the popular PHP micro-framework - [Slim Framework 3](https://www.slimframework.com/).

**The Application's Code**

My app is a very simple one that just routes different `get` requested to different templated pages. I'm using [`slimphp/Twig-View`](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View) for view rendering / templating.

Main `index.php` file looks like this:

```
// Require composer autoloader
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Application settings
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/app/settings.php';

// New Slim app instance
$app = new Slim\App( $settings );

// Add our dependencies to the container
require __DIR__ . '/app/dependencies.php';

// Require our route
require __DIR__ . '/app/routes.php';

// Run Slim
$app->run();
```

The `routes.php` file is like so:

```
// Creating routes

// Psr-7 Request and Response interfaces
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->group('/', function () {

    $this->get('', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {

        $vars = [
            'page' => [
            'title' => 'East End Ink',
            'description' => 'Best apparel company in Austin'
            ],
        ];

        return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig', $vars);    
    });

    $this->get('products', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {

        $vars = [
            'page' => [
            'title' => 'East End Ink',
            'description' => 'Best apparel company in Austin'
            ],
        ];
        return $this->view->render($response, 'products.twig', $vars);    
    });

    [...... cut out some repetition ....]

    $this->get('services', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {

        $vars = [
            'page' => [
            'title' => 'East End Ink',
            'description' => 'Best apparel company in Austin'
            ],
        ];
        return $this->view->render($response, 'services.twig', $vars);    
    });

});
```

The source code for the whole app is [HERE](https://github.com/zacharygcook/east-end-site).

**How I run the App Locally / Trying to Run in Production**

This is what it looks like for me to run the web application locally:

20 Second Video - http://tinypic.com/r/n6c5g7/9

I just run `php -S localhost:8080` and once at `localhost:8080` the app works great. The problem is, I do not know how to translate this to running the application online. I've deployed my source code to CloudWays and FortRabbit, both have somehow been successful at displaying the homepage.

CloudWays - http://phpstack-115365-328618.cloudwaysapps.com/:
[image: Homepage Shown on CloudWays]

FortRabbit - https://custom-5yx3.frb.io/:
[image: Homepage Shown on FortRabbit]

The error I get when I try to navigate to the routing of any other page on this staging environment is this:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at phpstack-115365-328618.cloudwaysapps.com Port 80
```

What I think it's doing is just serving up the php file there like php does locally if I go to the application's route at port 80 without running `php -S localhost:8080`.

17 Second Video of me reproducing same issue locally: http://tinypic.com/r/28s6n87/9

**Now the question is:**

How can I get this web application hosted at a place like CloudWays or FortRabbit. What in general am I trying to do to get it running there? And if you're kind enough, how specifically might I go about doing that?

**P.S.**
The site's source code is still public, so feel free to checkout it's [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/zacharygcook/east-end-site) to peruse files.

**P.P.S.**
I'm very grateful to any help you're able to provide. I'm a n00b and this arena, and will pay it back when I'm a more able/experienced PHP developer like I do in other areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your files from the repo.

First, I get the following error when checking out your website locally:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /var/www/htdocs/slim/app/routes.php on line 98

That's because a missing semicolon on line 97. I fixed that.

Then I can see the home page, but trying to go to the other pages gives a 500 error.

The problem for me is in your .htaccess file. You have this line:

```
RewriteBase /var/www/html/brand-builders-php-site/
```

and if I change it to this:

```
RewriteBase /
```

then everything works (I can load the pages)

Comment: sorry, guess I hadn't pushed the fix to the syntax error to master.

Comment: But OK, badass! That's literally all I had to do. Thanks so much man, I know my question was kind of an ignorant one.

Comment: Ya gotta learn somewhere. But yeah, when you have a site and it works, but then doesn't work on another server, it's usually server config. .htaccess is a local server config, so that's where I started, and as soon as I saw that RewriteBase I knew that was your problem. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Usually 500 errors are relating to the htaccess when using Slim 3, at least from when I was using it.

The other answer regarding the htaccess properly addresses this, I'd comment but not enough repair so I can only answer.